# Is a Kármán Rocket Possible?

Tags: rockets, aerodynamics, karman-line

Why are the rockets not razor sharp, skinnier and taper off at both ends farther to cut through air better? Would making a rocket more aerodynamic allow it to be more efficient flying as a "Kármán plane"?

In other words: **I know why the rocket bottom is flat and that is not what I am asking.** I want to know why rockets are so blunt? Could a rocket be designed to be more aerodynamic on the second stage for a sustaining prolong burn and flight at the Kármán line?

[image]
I added this picture to show how the rocket could be tampered at both ends.

[What would a "Kármán plane" look like, a bird, or a plane?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29721/what-would-a-k%c3%a1rm%c3%a1n-plane-look-like-a-bird-or-a-plane)

Comment: Partial dupe of [Why are the bottom of most stages flat?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26092/195)

Comment: To what end do you want a "Kármán rocket"? As soon as it's out of fuel, it's gonna reenter.

Comment: @RussellBorogove low altitude recon of another planet in theory you could get closer then ever and throttle up to escape orbit.

Comment: Bring a bigger telescope instead.

Comment: @RussellBorogove what data can be gathered from orbiting inside an atmosphere of a planet at the Kármán line compared to leo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are the rockets not razor sharp

Because then the payload fairing would spend a lot of mass for space that wasn't useful to enclose a payload.

> skinnier

The skinnier the rocket, the worse its volume-to-surface-area ratio, increasing its weight for a given capability. Additionally, some rockets like SpaceX's Falcon 9 are already skinny enough that flexion of the rocket body is a problem.

> and tamper off at both ends

The back end isn't tapered for a number of reasons, [discussed in an earlier QA](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26092/195).

> Would making a rocket more aerodynamic allow it to be more efficient flying
>   as a "Kármán plane"?

Less so, if anything; a longer, skinnier rocket is less able to make use of body lift. In any case, orbital launchers don't hang out at the Kármán line; they get past it and well above it in a big hurry.

For large launchers, aerodynamic drag produces only a small performance penalty -- only on the order of 1% of the ∆v produced is lost to drag. Making them pointier would increase weight or decrease payload volume to little benefit.